# Correct usage of ForEach -parallel in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I want to process a large number of URLs and grab the *.jpg file locations.
The problem is that the `$entry` in the second foreach is not threadsafe.
The script is firing hundreds of errors because the `$entry` is getting overwritten over and over.
When I move the inner `foreach` outside of the `ForEach-Object`, then its working fine but very slowly.
How can I process the split output properly within my `ForEach-Object` without getting these errors?

- `$array` just contains a huge amount of URLs
- `$clean_img_array` is the output array of the operation
- `$tmpArray` is the reference to `$clean_img_array` in order to use it within a parallel ForEach

Errors:

```
InvalidOperation:
Line |
  14 |                  [void]$tmpArray:clean_img_array.Add($entry);
     |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Snippet:

```
   $clean_img_array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@();

   $array | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        
        $web = Invoke-RestMethod $_;
        
        $i=1;
        foreach($entry in $web.Split("`"")){
            echo $entry;
            if($entry.IndexOf(".jpg") -ne -1 -And $entry.IndexOf("http") -ne -1){
                if($entry.IndexOf("?") -ne -1){
                    $tmpArray = $using:clean_img_array;
                    [void]$tmpArray.Add($entry.Substring(0, $entry.IndexOf('?')));
                }else{
                    $tmpArray = $using:Clean_img_array;
                    [void]$tmpArray:clean_img_array.Add($entry);
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    } -ThrottleLimit 20
```

Comment: thx for the input, I edited the question and added the Information you asked for
I just removed the threadSafeImgArray because this just bout the Progress bar and is neglectable for now 
if you have further question feel free to ask

Comment: How about something like `$clean_img_array = $array | foreach-object -parallel { ... }`

Comment: @js2010 im a bit confused about variable at the start, what does it do? is it like a return value?
can you provide me a source link because I don't get it from the Microsoft site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support!
I combined the answer from @js2012 with something of my own.
The return alone did not solve the thread unsave behavior of `$entry`, but clearly untangled the workflow.
But I used the inline version of `.foreach` with the pipe line variable `$_` wich happens
to be thread safe as it appears to me. Running now like a charm and also very fast for more than 2million entrys.

- `$array` holds the URLs to be processed
- `$clean_img_array` returns the grabbed image URLs

  ```
   $clean_img_array = $array | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

       $web = Invoke-RestMethod $_;
       $web.Split("`"").foreach({  
           if($_ -ne $null){
               if($_.IndexOf(".jpg") -ne -1 -And $_.IndexOf("http") -ne -1){
                   if($_.IndexOf("?") -ne -1){
                       return $_.Substring(0, $entry.IndexOf('?'));
                   }else{
                       return $_;
                   }           
               }
           }
       });

   } -ThrottleLimit 25
  ```

Comment: You don't need the word 'return', or the semicolons.

Comment: I freaking love the semicolons and I know they are obsolete :) and I will try it someday also without the return statement 
but thats more for my own readability

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example.  Both $a and $b are arrays.  $b is the result of the parallel loop.  It's like [example 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-12--retrieve-log-entries-in-parallel) in the docs.

```
$a = 1..10
$b = $a | foreach-object -parallel { $_ + 1 }

$b

2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: thanks for the example 
im a bit confused how I can combine this with the inner foreach wich I need to process the split result fast

Comment: for example just return `$entry.Substring(0, $entry.IndexOf('?'))` by itself.